# How to extract a text from a large string and change it

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a lot of markdown files that have some front matter data. This is the content of one such file (layout, title, etc aren't always in the same order):

```
---
layout: post
title: An awesome title
date: 2019-01-11 00:00:00
description: My description goes here.
---

A lot of paraghaps bellow...
```

I need to change the format and keep only the title. I need this:

```
# An awesome title

A lot of paraghaps bellow...
```

I tried a few regex methods, but I can't make them work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this out:

```
---(?:[\n\r]|.)*?(?<=title: )([^\n\r]+)(?:[\n\r]|.)*?---
```

As demonstrated here: **https://regex101.com/r/9O99Fz/1/**

## Explanation -

`(?:[\n\r]|.)*?` - after matching '---', the regex matches all characters until the next condition in the regex:
`(?<=title: )` - this is a positive lookbehind that tells the regex to match the text which is preceded by `title:`
`([^\n\r]+)` - since the title will be one sentence, this group matches the actual title you want by saying that it should not have a newline or carriage-return (this is the **capturing group 1**)
`(?:[\n\r]|.)*?---` just matches the last part of the 'details' section

---

Also, in the substitution part, `\1` is replaced by the title in the **capturing group 1**, and so the code should execute correctly :)

Answer (score 0):

```
---[\s\S]*?title:([^\r\n]*)[\s\S]*?---
```

https://regex101.com/r/SS3Orn/4

1. 1st capture group `([^\r\n]*)` : all characters up to newline after "title:"
2. [\s\S]* all characters, including newlines, up to "---"
3. Even works with multiple sample input on same page.